# Assembly output too complicated

Tags: assembly

This is a probably a very basic question, please bear with me.

I'm starting to get into reverse engineering following this pdf I found online: https://beginners.re/
I am, however, stuck at the very basic steps.

The relevant part from the PDF: [image: 1]]

When I try to compile my c++ code (which is the same as in the book) with the following command:

```
gcc main.cpp -S -O
```

This is the output I get:

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9FJ6.png)

Which, as you can see, is very different, and a lot more complicated than the supposed output written in the pdf. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both outputs show the same effective assembly code.  In both outputs, there is only a single instruction:

```
ret
```

The second example output is a variation of `ret` the reason for which is listed in [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526361/what-does-rep-ret-mean#20526918).

The *more complicated* output has several code organizational assembler directives.  These directives are not instructions.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand correctly, assembler directives are to assembly what preprocessor directives are to C?

Also, is there a way to generate a simplified output file similar to the one in the pdf (function names remaining, directives removed etc.), or did the author presumably manually clean up the codes himself?

Comment: The author probably cleaned up it himself. You can also use https://godbolt.org to quickly view disassembly for a given code